# mysql indexing - joining two tables

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have  a table T1 in which 2 columns are c1 and c2 .They are foreign key reference cols to col c3 in tabel U1.
 A query has something like `"select ....... from T1, U1 as Ux and U1 as Uy where T1.c1 = 'xyz' and T1.c1 = Ux.c3 and T1.c2 = Uy.c3"`

Which col , if indexed , give the best results. 
`c1` ***alone*** or a combination of `c1` ***and*** `c2` ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXPLAIN and just put your two scenarios. Try it yourself and you will easily spot the better query

Answer (score 0):

how about a join?

```
SELECT * FROM T1
INNER JOIN U1 ON U1.c3=T1.c1 AND U1.c3=T1.c2
WHERE T1.c1 = 'xyz'
```

I do not really get what you are trying to do but trying to get anything from this c1 and c2 must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your "c1" column is the only part of the query, and it is in the first position of the index in case of a compound index (c1, c2), then it would have no real impact.  It would still be optimized.  If "c1" was in the second position, no good... as it would have to in essence, cycle through each c2 for the c1 that matched.  That said, if your c2 column was some  awful value like a string of varchar 1000, it WOULD choke as it would have to consider the index key length and extra paging.  However, indexing on such a combination would not be considered common anyhow.